# View log files kept in multiple pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-eks

I am running a server in eks in multiple pods. When my server runs it creates a log file. How do I view these log files together according to timeline when multiple pods are involved.

eg:

pod-1 ----> log.txt

pod-2 ----> log.txt

pod-3 ----> log.txt

Main error logs will be shown in terminal and I know I can access it using `kubectl logs -l`.
Am asking about some other kind of logs which I am storing in files.

Answer (score 0):

If your main process doesn't write to stdout it's best practice to have a logging sidecar, write the logs to a shared volume and have the sidecar tail the file.

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: main-app
    image: some-image   
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log # have main-app log to /var/log/log.txt
  - name: log-sidecar
    image: busybox:1.28
    args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'tail -n+1 -F /var/log/log.txt']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log
  volumes:
  - name: varlog
    emptyDir: {}
```

Now your logging solution (like fluentd or fluentbit) can fetch the logs and export them to your logging infrastructure, like kibana or the cloud provider specific (like cloudwatch on aws), depending on what you have/use.

If you want to follow them from your terminal, you can use [stern](https://github.com/stern/stern) to follow multiple container logs of certain pods:

`stern -n <namespace> -l component=server -c log-sidecar`

supposing all pods are labeled with `component: server`